Error: Constructor for "ion-app#undefined" was not found after upgrade to Angular 18.1 and Ionic 8
I Have just upgraded my Ionic v7 / Angular 16 app to Ionic v8, Angular v18, and now I get runtime errors where it looks like it can't load any of the Ionic components.

If I look into my <app>\.angular\cache\18.1.1\vite\deps folder, I do not see anything starting with Ion...

I did go through all the Angular and Ionic upgrade instructions, and it compiles fine, but I get these runtime errors.
I am not sure if this is relevant, but there are also updates to the Angular build...

Ionic info:
$ ionic info
 Ionic:

   Ionic CLI                     : 7.2.0 (C:\Users\peter\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@ionic\cli)
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 8.2.5
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 18.1.1
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 18.1.1
   @angular/cli                  : 18.1.1
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 11.0.1

Cordova:

   Cordova CLI       : 11.0.0
   Cordova Platforms : android 13.0.0
   Cordova Plugins   : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.2.0, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 5.0.0, (and 13 other plugins)

Utility:

   cordova-res : 0.15.4
   native-run  : not installed globally

System:

   NodeJS : v20.15.1 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)
   npm    : 10.7.0
   OS     : Windows 10

What might be missing here (or how I can further diagnose)?
Update 1
I also just noticed the following in the terminal window...
ng] Application bundle generation complete. [4.600 seconds]
[ng] Watch mode enabled. Watching for file changes...
[ng] NOTE: Raw file sizes do not reflect development server per-request transformations.
[ng] Re-optimizing dependencies because lockfile has changed
[ng]   ➜  Local:   http://127.0.0.1:8100/
[ng]   ➜  press h + enter to show help
[ng] 8:02:56 am [vite] warning: 
[ng] C:/dev/my-app/.angular/cache/18.1.1/vite/deps/chunk-GQGXXH53.js
[ng] 900|      return i[n];
[ng] 901|    }
[ng] 902|    return import("./".concat(a, ".entry.js").concat("")).then(function(e2) {
[ng]    |                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[ng] 903|      {
[ng] 904|        cmpModules.set(a, e2);
[ng] See https://github.com/rollup/plugins/tree/master/packages/dynamic-import-vars#limitations for supported dynamic import formats. If this is intended to be left as-is, you can use the /* @vite-ignore */ comment inside the import() call to suppress this warning.
[ng]
[ng]   Plugin: vite:import-analysis
[ng]   File: C:/dev/my-app/.angular/cache/18.1.1/vite/deps/chunk-GQGXXH53.js?v=e850c948
[ng] The file does not exist at "C:/dev/my-app/.angular/cache/18.1.1/vite/deps/ion-app_8.entry.js" which is in the optimize deps directory. The dependency might be incompatible with the dep optimizer. Try adding it to `optimizeDeps.exclude`.
[ng] The file does not exist at "C:/dev/my-app/.angular/cache/18.1.1/vite/deps/ion-menu_3.entry.js" which is in the optimize deps directory. The dependency might be incompatible with the dep optimizer. Try adding it to `optimizeDeps.exclude`.
[ng] The file does not exist at "C:/dev/my-app/.angular/cache/18.1.1/vite/deps/ion-item_8.entry.js" which is in the optimize deps directory. The dependency might be incompatible with the dep optimizer. Try adding it to `optimizeDeps.exclude`.
[ng] The file does not exist at "C:/dev/my-app/.angular/cache/18.1.1/vite/deps/ion-loading.entry.js" which is in the optimize deps directory. The dependency might be incompatible with the dep optimizer. Try adding it to `optimizeDeps.exclude`.
[ng] The file does not exist at "C:/dev/my-app/.angular/cache/18.1.1/vite/deps/ion-app_8.entry.js" which is in the optimize deps directory. The dependency might be incompatible with the dep optimizer. Try adding it to `optimizeDeps.exclude`.
[ng] The file does not exist at "C:/dev/my-app/.angular/cache/18.1.1/vite/deps/ion-menu_3.entry.js" which is in the optimize deps directory. The dependency might be incompatible with the dep optimizer. Try adding it to `optimizeDeps.exclude`.
[ng] The file does not exist at "C:/dev/my-app/.angular/cache/18.1.1/vite/deps/ion-item_8.entry.js" which is in the optimize deps directory. The dependency might be incompatible with the dep optimizer. Try adding it to `optimizeDeps.exclude`.
[ng] The file does not exist at "C:/dev/my-app/.angular/cache/18.1.1/vite/deps/ion-loading.entry.js" which is in the optimize deps directory. The dependency might be incompatible with the dep optimizer. Try adding it to `optimizeDeps.exclude`.


I had the same issue. Check your package.json and main.ts files. In my case, I had to replace importProvidersFrom(IonicModule.forRoot() with provideIonicAngular() in main.ts. After that, everything worked fine.

Thanks, it is too late now, I reverted and started again. I Just had to make sure I did not opt into the new Angular es build, as Ionic components need to be stand alone to use it be able to use it as mentioned here
